# apache tomcat 8.5 not starting due to Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError log4j

Tags: java, java-8, log4j2, tomcat8.5, eclipse-classpath

I have Eclipse java(1.8) web project and try to configure to run on eclipes with local tomcat 8.5 server
I'M not able to run eclipse the JAVA WEb project on apache tomcat 8.5 server.Eventhough i have set the log4j jars into project class path im getting the **NoClassDefFoundError** error for log4j.

**Eclipse project class path**
i have added following jars on to Java BUild path -> Libraries -> add External jars

- log4j-api-2.17.1.jar
- log4j-core-2.17.1.jar

```
Feb 21, 2024 11:30:06 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:MYAPP' did not find a matching property.
Feb 21, 2024 11:30:06 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.5.15
Feb 21, 2024 11:30:06 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          May 5 2017 11:03:04 UTC
Feb 21, 2024 11:30:06 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         8.5.15.0
Feb 21, 2024 11:30:06 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows 10
Feb 21, 2024 11:30:06 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            10.0
Feb 21, 2024 11:30:06 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
Feb 21, 2024 11:30:06 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             D:\softwares\java\jdk1.8.191\jre
Feb 21, 2024 11:30:06 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_191-b12
Feb 21, 2024 11:30:06 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Feb 21, 2024 11:30:06 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         D:\softwares\eclipse_workspaces\MYAPP_devops3\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
Feb 21, 2024 11:30:06 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         D:\Users\xxxx\Projects\apache-tomcat-8.5.15
Feb 21, 2024 11:30:06 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=D:\softwares\eclipse_workspaces\MYAPP_devops3\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
Feb 21, 2024 11:30:06 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=D:\Users\xxxx\Projects\apache-tomcat-8.5.15
Feb 21, 2024 11:30:06 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=D:\softwares\eclipse_workspaces\MYAPP_devops3\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps
Feb 21, 2024 11:30:06 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=D:\Users\xxxx\Projects\apache-tomcat-8.5.15\endorsed
Feb 21, 2024 11:30:06 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
Feb 21, 2024 11:30:06 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [D:\softwares\java\jdk1.8.191\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;D:/softwares/eclipse-jee-2022-12//plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_17.0.6.v20230204-1729/jre/bin/server;D:/softwares/eclipse-jee-2022-12//plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_17.0.6.v20230204-1729/jre/bin;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\usr\bin;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\bin;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\jdk-11.0.16.101-hotspot\bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\wbin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Enterprise Vault\EVClient\x64\;C:\Windows\CCM;D:\Users\support130163ws\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;D:\Public\Projects\apache-jmeter-5.5\bin;D:\Public\Projects\apache-jmeter-5.5\bin;C:\Program Files\IBM\MQ\bin64;C:\Program Files\IBM\MQ\bin;C:\Program Files\IBM\MQ\tools\c\samples\bin64;C:\Program Files\IBM\MQ\tools\c\samples\bin;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;D:\Users\xxxx\Projects\Terraform;D:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;D:\softwares\java\jdk1.8.191\bin;D:\Users\xxxx\Projects\gradle-1.10\bin;D:\softwares\Go\bin;D:\softwares\python-3.12.0\;;D:\softwares\eclipse-jee-2022-12;;.]
Feb 21, 2024 11:30:06 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Feb 21, 2024 11:30:07 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Feb 21, 2024 11:30:07 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Feb 21, 2024 11:30:07 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Feb 21, 2024 11:30:07 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 822 ms
Feb 21, 2024 11:30:07 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service [Catalina]
Feb 21, 2024 11:30:07 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.15
Feb 21, 2024 11:30:08 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/MYAPP]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:872)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/MYAPP]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/apache/logging/log4j/Logger;
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1916)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredFields(Introspection.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadFieldsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationServletAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:66)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:328)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:778)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:299)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5105)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1285)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1119)
    ... 19 more

Feb 21, 2024 11:30:08 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:793)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:656)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:355)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:495)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:947)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:872)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more

Feb 21, 2024 11:30:08 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8012]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:656)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:355)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:495)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:793)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:947)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 11 more

Feb 21, 2024 11:30:08 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Feb 21, 2024 11:30:08 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Feb 21, 2024 11:30:08 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service [Catalina]
Feb 21, 2024 11:30:08 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Feb 21, 2024 11:30:08 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Feb 21, 2024 11:30:08 AM org.apache.catalina.deploy.NamingResourcesImpl cleanUp
WARNING: Failed to retrieve JNDI naming context for container [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/MYAPP]] so no cleanup was performed for that container
javax.naming.NamingException: No naming context bound to this class loader
    at org.apache.naming.ContextBindings.getClassLoader(ContextBindings.java:268)
    at org.apache.catalina.deploy.NamingResourcesImpl.cleanUp(NamingResourcesImpl.java:993)
    at org.apache.catalina.deploy.NamingResourcesImpl.stopInternal(NamingResourcesImpl.java:976)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:226)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5443)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:226)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:264)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:854)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.destroyInternal(ContainerBase.java:1036)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:297)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:854)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.destroyInternal(ContainerBase.java:1036)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:297)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.destroyInternal(StandardService.java:585)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:297)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.destroyInternal(StandardServer.java:883)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:297)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:660)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:355)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:495)
```

Comment: Usually log4j is configured in server.xml , but like anythiing there are other ways. However, the error seems to not be able to find /MYAPP web application. check your web.xml and the MYAPP folder context.xml in META-INF

Comment: In "Build path" you configure you compile-time dependencies, the runtime dependencies are configured in "Deployment assembly".